# Why the final result varies?

Tags: function, syntax, return

When returning from a function, The following coding style does **NOT** seem to work -

```
    return (int) minim(mid-l,r-mid) + (int) (mid+mid==n)?1:0;
```

But the following code is working fine -

```
    int x = minim(mid-l,r-mid);
    int y = (mid+mid==n)?1:0;
    return x+y ;
```

**mid, l, r, n** are all integers.

Can someone please help me understand why?

Comment: If you find the answers below useful you should consider accepting one of them by clicking on the check-mark icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parentheses as '+' takes [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) over the ternary operator '?:'

```
return (int) minim(mid-l,r-mid) + ((int) (mid+mid==n)?1:0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to operator [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

```
return (int) minim(mid-l,r-mid) + (int) (mid+mid==n)?1:0;
```

means

```
return ((int) minim(mid-l,r-mid) + (int) (mid+mid==n))?1:0;
```

not

```
return (int) minim(mid-l,r-mid) + ((int) (mid+mid==n))?1:0);
```